# Why are inline functions allowed to manipulate private member variables?

Tags: c++, inline, private-members

Suppose I have a class with an two inline functions:

```
class Class {
public:
   void numberFunc();
   int getNumber() { return number; }
private:
   int number;
};

inline void Class::numberFunc()
{
   number = 1937;
}
```

I instantiate that class and I call both of the functions in the class:

```
int main() {
   Class cls;
   cls.numberFunc();
   cout << cls.getNumber() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I understand that both inline functions are still members of the class, but it is also my understanding that the code within the body of an inline function is just inserted in place of where it was called.  It seems that, as a result of that insert, I should not be able to directly access the member variable `number` because, as far as I know, the code in `main()` to the compiler would look like:

```
main() {
   Class cls;
   cls.number = 1937;
   cout << cls.number << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why I am still able to access those private members, or correct me on my understanding of inline functions?  I know that compilers have the option to ignore the `inline` on some functions; is that what is happening here?

Output:

> 1937

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rules for accessing private members of a class are enforced by the compiler on your C++ code. These rules don't apply directly to the output of the compiler, which is the code that a computer exectues.

Answer (score 7):

The  `inline` keyword does mean that programmer thinks that compiler may if it so wants to insert the code at place of call. Compiler may inline other functions too without the keyword. Compiler may think that programmer is fool and ignore the keyword and not inline. It is all by C++ standard.

The inline member function is otherwise quite normal member function. No other privileges or restrictions.

Inlines do not cause errors that the function is defined by multiple compilation units (that include the header file where the inline function is defined). That may be one reason why people write inline functions.

Comment: `inline` also allows the violation of the ODR rule as well.

Comment: I will add it, thanks, possibly that is one reason why the inlines are used.

Answer (score 5):

The `private` access specifier is a restriction on the users of the class(the programmers), not on the compiler.  The compiler can do whatever it wants, as long as the observable behavior of the program is the same.

Comment: No - a conforming compiler cannot do what it wants - the access-specifier are evaluated during a particular step of compilation - after they are not checked again.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: A conforming compiler can evauluate access levels whenever it wants, as long it appears as though they were evaluated at that particular step.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: 1.9 paragraph 1

Comment: 1.9.1 in C++14882-2011 is under Program Execution - what does that have to do with compile time evaluations of  access-specifier's during compile time

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Did you read it?  Not just the header, but the text?  The footer note is particularly illuminating: *"an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this International Standard as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed"*

Comment: This is for execution full stop - it does not mention compiling code - it is not RELEVANT

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I'm sorry, you're wrong, but I won't belabor the point.  The quote is clear, you'll just have to come to realize it for yourself.

Comment: Explain to me how 1.9.1 affects access specifiers at runtime - when they are clearly evaluates at compile time. This has nothing to do with inline's

Comment: @AdrianCornish: *"Explain to me how 1.9.1 affects access specifiers at runtime"* -- I have no idea what you are talking about.  That has absolutely nothing to do with anything I said.  This is what I said: *"The compiler can do whatever it wants, as long as the observable behavior of the program is the same."*  The compiler doesn't do *anything* at runtime, so obviously we're talking about compile time here.